# Want to change incoming request to identity or openIDConnect

Tags: azure, asp.net-core, oauth, azure-api-management, azure-policy

I see from Microsoft Docs, they provide only these 3 basic, certificate and MSI in the policy. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-authentication-policies#AuthenticationPolicies

Does that mean I can not accomplish the OIDC?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**SHORT ANSWER:** No changes in API Management if you are changing the authentication of API Consumers with Backend API.

Long Answer explaining how authentication policies are not related to API consumer authentication is given below.

**Basic Concept**

API Management is in the middle of your API and your consumer.

From terminology perspective, your API in this case is called as Backend API. Frontend API is the URL of API management, which can be shared with your consumer.

Refer [this page for further basic terminology](https://manojchoudhari.wordpress.com/2019/03/10/introduction-to-azure-api-management/) about API Management.

In my opinion, there are two different questions: one about consumer OAuth authentication and other about which authentication policy is required to be configured in APIM.

**Consumer Authentication**

So, if you want your consumer to get authenticated using JWT Authentication or OAuth authentication, the flow is simple.  The consumer will get the authentication token from the identity service and then use that token to call your API.

As long as you do not modify it using API Management policies, it should work.   API Management is not required to know the Authority or any other details about authority.

**APIM Authentication Policies**

Based on your design, you can choose if Backend API (i.e. the API which you hosted in APIM) should have logic to authenticate the Frontend API - to ensure that only known party is calling your API.

As per [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-authentication-policies#AuthenticationPolicies), you can configure :

- Basic Authentication policy and send username and password with every request to backend API
- Certificate authentication policy and send certificate thumbprint with every request to backend API
- Managed Identity to use Azure AD authentication.

All these three policies just help your backend API to ensure  the identity of the caller (i.e. APIM Fronend API in this case).  This has nothing to do with Consumer Authentication and OAuth.

*For ex.  You can set up  your API in such a way that consumer needs to get authenticated using Facebook authentication.  And in addition, you can have certificate authentication to identify that only valid APIM instance is redirecting the consumer request from Frontend API to Backend API.*

Hope this clarifies.

Comment: I think the answer is still relevant.  If you want to call any third party API that is protected because of some other authentication, you should call it from the code rather than configuring anything in APIM,    Because APIM policies only matter about your backend API.  The APIM authentication policies are applicable only for communication between APIM and your API, not third party API.    Hope this clarifies.

Answer (score 0):

As the [article](https://manojchoudhari.wordpress.com/2019/03/12/azure-security-in-api-management/) said:

> If your backend API is already secured with OAuth2.0 using any platform, then the API consumers should pass the Authorization header to the API management.
> You do not need to add any policy in the API Management. **The header would be sent by API Consumer and API Management would send the same header to the Backend API**.

Use basic authentication and [set header manually](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-authentication-policies).

```
<authentication-basic username="username" password="password" />
<set-header name="Authorization" exists-action="override">
   <value>@("Bearer " + (string)context.Variables["token"])</value>
</set-header>
```